# How to join two methods

Tags: c#

how coudl I join these two methods if only middle line is differnt ?

```
public static WeekendElectricityReportResult CalculateWeekendElectricityReportResult(string dataFilPath)
        {
            string newFile = CopyFile(dataFilPath);

            GetOperationClient().GetWeeklyEleReport(newFile);

            RemoveNotUsedFiles(dataFilPath, newFile);

            return ReadCalculations<WeekendElectricityReportResult>(newFile);
        }

        public static WeekendGasReportResult CalculateWeekendGasReportResult(string dataFilPath)
        {
            string newFile = CopyFile(dataFilPath);

            GetOperationClient().GetWeeklyGasReport(newFile);

            RemoveNotUsedFiles(dataFilPath, newFile);

            return ReadCalculations<WeekendGasReportResult>(newFile);
        }
```

If I join them to one generic method how to distincs which middle method to use GetWeeklyEleReport or GetWeeklyGasReport ?

Comment: I know how to create generic method but I was wondering how to distinct inside which wcf method to use depends on caller.

Comment: Anyone should be able to read your code and understand what it's doing. You have a method `GetWeeklyGasReport()` which sounds like it returns something but you aren't assigning a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a delegate. Since you are not returning a value in your middle function, you could use the `Action` object:

```
public static WeekendReportResult CalculateWeekendReportResult(string dataFilPath, Action<string> del)
    {
        string newFile = CopyFile(dataFilPath);

       del(newFile);

        RemoveNotUsedFiles(dataFilPath, newFile);

        return ReadCalculations<WeekendGasReportResult>(newFile);
    }
```

Then you would call this method like this:

```
Action<string> del = delegate(string file) {   
    GetOperationClient().GetWeeklyEleReport(file);
};
var eleReport = CalculateWeekendReportResult(file, del);

Action<string> del2 = delegate(string file) {   
    GetOperationClient().GetWeeklyGasReport(file);
};
var gasReport = CalculateWeekendReportResult(file, del2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static T CalculateReportResult<T>(string dataFilPath, Action<OperationClient, string> getAct, Func<string, T> readFunc)
{
    string newFile = CopyFile(dataFilPath);

    getAct(GetOperationClient(), newFile);

    RemoveNotUsedFiles(dataFilPath, newFile);

    return readFunc(newFile);
}
```

then you can do:

```
public static WeekendElectricityReportResult CalculateWeekendElectricityReportResult(string dataFilPath)
{
    return CalculateWeekendElectricityReportResult(dataFilPath, (client, path) => { client.GetWeeklyEleReport(path); }, file => ReadCalculations<WeekendElectricityReportResult>(file));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pattern `Template Method`. In C# it is possible to implement without inheritance, just passing delegate to template method.

```
public static T CalculateWeekendReportsResult<T>(string dataFilPath, Action<string> action)
{
    string newFile = CopyFile(dataFilPath);

    action(newFile);

    RemoveNotUsedFiles(dataFilPath, newFile);

    return ReadCalculations<T>(newFile);
}
```

Usage is:

```
var report = CalculateWeekendReportsResult<WeekendElectricityReportResult>
                     (filePath, GetOperationClient().GetWeeklyEleReport);
```

or

```
var report = CalculateWeekendReportsResult<WeekendGasReportResult>
                     (filePath, GetOperationClient().GetWeeklyGasReport);
```